# Edit rejected by Community

Tags: support, editing, community-user

I recently had an [edit](https://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/62159) rejected by, among others, [Community](https://mathoverflow.net/users/-1/community), with the rejection message "This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed."  I have two questions about this.

First, and probably less importantly, I know that Community is not really a person, and that it own suggested edits from anonymous users; but under what circumstances will Community own edit *rejections*?

Second, and more importantly for me, I am confused about "what should have been changed."  Aside from editing the title (which I forgot to do), the actual [accepted edit](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/234662/revisions) seems almost identical to mine.  What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several reasons why the Community user may show up as rejecting the edit. A detailed explanation is given on the central Meta site [Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits)

The short is, rejections happens:

1. when a parallel edit of a user with full editing privileges conflicts with a suggested one. This happens by unfortunate timing and means  nothing for the quality of the specific edit, it is just a quirk of how the system works.
2. when somebody decides to choose "reject and edit" in the review-queue. Abstractly this can be taken as meaning there was a need for editing but the specific edit was not a good one, and this is what the message is trying to convey.

For the specific case it was the second that happened and it was the post owner who decided to chose this option (one more experience user had approve your edit).

However, for the specific case, I would not make too much of it. I think your edit was fine. OP may just have not really understood the interface, being very new to the site, or they may just not have liked their post being edited, or still something else.

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't sure if the rejection message was a generic one (as @StefanKohl suggested in a now-deleted comment), or if there was really some important difference between my suggested, and the accepted, edit that escaped me.

Comment: You are welcome. I included some remark on the message now. It is generic, but in the situation where it is used  there is always another edit so at least abstractly it makes sense to refer to the edit.  Yet, note that the edit referred to here is the one in revision 2 by OP, not the subsequent ones similar to yours.  Thus, in this specific case the message does not really make sense (as the action taken by the reviewing OP was not optimal).